# Unresponsive screen, except for when in power saving mode?

Tags: pokemon-go

UPDATE: Power saving mode is actually very rarely fixing this problem. When I first posted this,  power saving mode had turned for the first time while playing it, and it seemed to fix it. Now however power saver doesn't do anything to help it, although sometimes it seems to smooth the app out a little.

TLDR; Screen is very unresponsive, power saver stops it. Why??

I have an HTC M8 and have been having problems with Pokemon Go. The touch screen becomes quite unresponsive and laggy when playing this game. I have to tap/swipe multiple (sometimes ridiculous amounts) times for things to register. This hasn't ever happened before on this phone, and doesn't happen with any other app. As soon as I leave the game, the screen becomes normal again. The phone is normally never laggy or unresponsive. The game however is playable, but it makes the more complicated mechanics of the game impossible (timing your Pokeball throw, and gym battles). I thought this might be something that couldn't be fixed, but I noticed today when power saver mode turned on, that everything suddenly became fine! The screen was very responsive and the game played perfectly, for the first time since I got it. Any clue as to what could be causing this and what I can do to fix it? I have a custom ROM and kernel: CM13.0 nightly, CM kernel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your phone battery temperature do when you play this game? In the sun of high noon my phone's battery can skyrocket above 95 degrees, severely impacting the performance of the game. Power Saver fixing this wouldn't prove anything with battery temp, but it still bears asking.

Comment: do you have developer mode enabled?

Comment: I have noticed the battery temp getting high, and it does seem to affect the game's performance, but I still have trouble even when it runs cold (and it's pretty cold here atm). Yes I do have developer mode enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same Problem it's a Bug with the Gyroscope Driver in [Cyanogenmod for the HTC One M8](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/MC-65). Fix is not yet Released but you may try the Test-Version

Comment: Does this mean if I use another rom/kernel it would be fixed? Because I would be perfectly happy with that

Comment: you may also wait for the update/or test the update, but yeah any rom which does not use that gyroscope driver could work

Comment: The bug is fixed in the latest nightly builds for CM 13, I tried the Build vom 18. July 2016. You may want to update your rom, for me the bug is now gone and pokemon go is responsive and finally playable.

Comment: Just updated to the latest build, everything is fine now! Thank you