# Pokemon Go freezes when using Battery Saving option

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S5 and I tried to use the Battery Saver option. The problem happens randomly when I turn on Battery Saver then put my phone in my pocket. After I jog for about 10 mins or so and I take my phone out to try and click on something (ex. Pokespot or gym), it does not respond. However, I can still see the animations of the Pokespot on the map, its just that it won't respond to any input.

Does anyone know of a fix other than restarting the app every time it happens?

UPDATE: Found a solution to this by using an app called [Caffeine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.syntaxa.caffeine), checkout the answer below for details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresponsive screen, except for when in power saving mode?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273692/unresponsive-screen-except-for-when-in-power-saving-mode)

Comment: @Jouramie that looks like the opposite problem

Comment: I had noticed this as well with my brand-new Samsung Galaxy S7. I guess it's just a bug; my fix was to turn off the battery saver mode.

Comment: @nasukkin Ok thanks, I'll just keep it without battery saver for now. It would be cool if Niantic would allow Pokemon Go to run while the lock screen is on.

Comment: Been a few days; version is still 0.29.2 so I'm not entirely surprised to find that as of my jog this morning it still isn't fixed. The only solution remains to prevent your phone from locking entirely, which is a shame because by the time I'm reaching my the 10km mark, my phone's battery has all but drained by a good 80%. Ugh... Niantic plz...

Comment: @nasukkin I recommend you use the Caffeine app and put your screen timeout as low as possible. You can setup the Caffeine app to run only when Pokemon Go is active. So basically when you go on your run the Caffeine app will prevent it from locking and after the screen timeout duration it will dim the brightness on your screen. This works well if your pockets don't accidentally cause an active tap on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your answers @TimPenner @KevinTian. I actually found a neat way to get around this when I was browsing Reddit.

There's an app called [Caffeine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.syntaxa.caffeine) which prevents the phone from going to sleep (lock screen) whenever a certain application is in use (Pokemon Go). Instead it dims the screen after the timeout period that usually would cause the phone to go to the lock screen.

So now when I go jogging and I put the phone in my pocket it will stay on indefinitely plus it dims the screen after the 1 min timeout period to save battery.

Answer (score 3):

As of 0.29.2 the fix is to disable Battery Save mode.

Note: the best battery saver option available is an external battery pack.

Answer (score 2):

As of now there is no fix. I have the same issue often when I use battery save as well. It's just a bug that hopefully Niantic will patch in the near future.

If this happens with pokemon near you then simply relogging will allow you to catch the pokemon again.